# VSCode looking for file in wrong directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, project

I'm working on Laravel project. When I want VSCode jump to class's file in vendor, just got issue that it can't open file in correct location.

My working directory is `C:\wamp64\www\merchant` but VSCode try to open the file from `C:\wamp64\www\wallet`

My question is that is there anyway to tell VSCode the correct working directory?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

delete folder `.phpls` (`~/.phpls` or `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\PHP Language Server\` on Windows)

is the way to clear VSCode PHP extension server cache.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. :D

So, VSCode caches these reference on a global - not a per-project - basis? So, a class name in project1 can end up resolving to an identically class name in project2? That seems... sub-optimal.

Comment: It occurs to me that it might not be VSCode core that is doing this, but the PHP extension. Still, kind of odd...